# Passing a instance of a class

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

So, I'm doing some customs transitions for my app and I'm having a problem passing a self instance to the transition delegate of the presenting class. I know the problem is related to the instance because protocol's methods are not executing.

I presume I'm missing something but I can not find what.

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let detailVC = DetailVC()
    let animationController = AnimationController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView?.delegate = self
        collectionView?.dataSource = self

        detailVC.transitioningDelegate = self

        collectionView?.register(ControllerCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "klk")
        collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = false
        collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 80, bottom: 0, right: 10)
        let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout?.scrollDirection = .horizontal

    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "klk", for: indexPath) as! ControllerCell
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width * 0.6, height: view.frame.height * 0.5)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        animationController.originFrame = cell?.frame
        present(DetailVC(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension ViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return animationController
    }
}
```

**DetailVC**

```
class DetailVC: UIViewController {

    var cellFrame: CGRect?

    let label: UILabel = {
       let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.textColor = .white
        lbl.text = "Quitar"
        lbl.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100)
        lbl.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return lbl
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(label)
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        label.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissing)))
    }

    func dismissing() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you using storyboard? I think you need to use `detailVC` instead of `DetailVC()` in this statement  `present(DetailVC(), animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: @3stud1ant3 I know I was missing something. Yes that was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the delegate on the `detailVC` and then you are presenting a new instance that is why your delegate method is not being called.

So I think you need to use `detailVC` instead of `DetailVC()` in this statement `present(DetailVC(), animated: true, completion: nil)`